# ReactiveRecyclerViewAdapter not reacting to changes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, dynamic-data, reactiveui

I'm trying to use ReactiveRecyclerViewAdapter to update my RecyclerView based on the SourceList on my ViewModel, but there's not much documentation around this, but I should not be the only person struggling with this.

ViewModel:

```
 public class PassportScreenViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    readonly IAccountService _accountService;

    public PassportScreenViewModel(IAccountService accountService = null)
    {
        _accountService = accountService ?? Locator.Current.GetService<IAccountService>();
        SchoolChoices = new SourceList<SchoolDataModel>();
        SchoolChoices.Add(new SchoolDataModel(new SchoolChoice() { Name = "My simple test" }));
        SchoolChoices.Add(new SchoolDataModel(new SchoolChoice() { Name = "My simple tes 2" }));
        AddSchoolCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => {
            SchoolChoices.Edit(x => x.Add(new SchoolDataModel(new SchoolChoice() { Name = "My simple test " + SchoolChoices.Count })));
        });
    }

    [Reactive] public string Headline { get; set; }
    [Reactive] public string Title { get; set; }
    [Reactive] public string Company { get; set; }
    [Reactive] public SourceList<SchoolDataModel> SchoolChoices { get; set; }

    public ReactiveCommand AddSchoolCommand { get; set; }
}
```

My Fragment:

```
[WireUpResource("recyclerView_passport_schools")]
    public RecyclerView SchoolsRecycler { get; private set; }

    [WireUpResource("textview_passport_addschool")]
    public Button AddSchoolButton { get; private set; }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_passportscreen, container, false);
        this.WireUpControls(view);

        this.ViewModel = new PassportScreenViewModel();
        Photo.Click += Photo_Click;

        this.BindCommand(ViewModel, viewModel => viewModel.AddSchoolCommand, myView => myView.AddSchoolButton);

        var adapter = new SchoolReactiveAdapter(ViewModel.SchoolChoices.Connect());
        SchoolsRecycler.HasFixedSize = true;
        SchoolsRecycler.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Activity));
        SchoolsRecycler.SetAdapter(adapter);

        ViewModel.SchoolChoices.Connect().Subscribe(x =>
        {
            //adapter = new SchoolReactiveAdapter(ViewModel.SchoolChoices.Connect());
            //SchoolsRecycler.SwapAdapter(adapter, true);
        });

        return view;
    }
```

And my Adapter:

```
public class SchoolReactiveAdapter : ReactiveRecyclerViewAdapter<SchoolDataModel>
{
    public SchoolReactiveAdapter(IObservable<IChangeSet<SchoolDataModel>> backingList) : base(backingList)
    {
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        var itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.item_school, parent, false);
        return new MySchoolViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    public class MySchoolViewHolder : ReactiveRecyclerViewViewHolder<SchoolDataModel>
    {
        [WireUpResource("textview_schoolitem_name")]
        public TextView SchoolName { get; private set; }

        public MySchoolViewHolder(View view) : base(view)
        {
            this.WireUpControls();
            this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Name, v => v.SchoolName.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

If I uncomment this:

```
  ViewModel.SchoolChoices.Connect().Subscribe(x =>
        {
            //adapter = new SchoolReactiveAdapter(ViewModel.SchoolChoices.Connect());
            //SchoolsRecycler.SwapAdapter(adapter, true);
        });
```

this will swap the adapter and the new Item will show up, but I think the Adapter should react to the ChangeSet from the ViewModel when I do Connect();

```
var adapter = new SchoolReactiveAdapter(ViewModel.SchoolChoices.Connect());
```

And even if List get's a new item, RecyclerView doesn't get updated. There's no documentation about how to fully set up a bound RecyclerView with ReactiveUI at least I couldn't find it, any of you can help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to fix it?